# Having local varible inside a class which is on the heap in C++

Tags: c++

Assume I've this class:

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node();
        Node(const std::string key);
        ~Node();
        std::string& getKey ();
    private:
        std::string key; 
        Node* next;
};
```

If I do:

```
Node* n = new Node(2);
```

Where will be the var `key` located?
On the stack or in the dynamic heap like it's containing object `n`?

Also, when will be this var freed?

Comment: It is allocated on the heap, and will be deleted when you call `delete n;`

Comment: Heap, if there is a heap.